# Failed to load resource (css/js) AWS Lambda Express Node

Tags: html, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda

I am building a web app using AWS Lambda. I can run the app locally, but when I deploy it on AWS, the app is unable to load static resources.

app.js

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
});
```

and in my index.html, this is how I reference the resources

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/gradients.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="assets/js/angular.min-1.4.7.js"></script>
```

The structure of my directory is

```
My App/
  |app.js
  |index.js
  |public/
     |index.html
     |assets/
       |css/
       |js/
```

Based on my research, having the app sit in a lambda function shouldn't require special permissions to access these resources.

Answer (score -1):

After looking at my CloudWatch logs, I realized that when I request "/assets/css/bootstrap.css", the lambda function isn't being called. That helped me realize that I first need to configure my API Gateway to handle proxies. By default most API Gateways will just have a GET and POST under "/". To enable, create a proxy resource and create a get method that triggers the lambda function your express app is sitting on. This will all your API gateway to take requests inside of the root directory.

Comment: Hi, I know it's been a long time but I'm facing the same issue and I'm pretty new to serverless, could you please elaborate on your answer if you recall how you fixed it please?